# php abstract classes and interfaces

Tags: php, class, interface, abstract, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following scenario:

```
    abstract class Contractor {
     // Generic contractor methods...         
    }

    abstract class PrivatePerson extends Contractor {
     // Adds methods specific to private contractors
    }

     abstract class Company extends Contractor {
     // Adds methods specific to Company contractors
    }

    class CustomerPrivate extends PrivatePerson {
     // Customers that are contractors, but physical persons
    }

   class CustomerCompany extends Company {
     // Customers that are contractors, but companies
    }
```

And the same happens with suppliers and dealers, which can be private persons or companies. The problem now is the following: how to force object of class CustomerPrivate and CustomerCompany to be, at the same time, of class Customer (which I have not defined yet) and the same for suppliers and dealers. It is a good practice to use interfaces in such a case?

```
    interface Customer {
    }

     class PrivateCustomer extends PrivatePerson implements Customer {
     // Customers that are physical persons, but are CUSTOMERS!
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

```
class CustomerPrivate extends PrivatePerson
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if( $this instanceof Customer )
        {
            //CODE
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \Exception("YOU ERROR MESSAGE", 1);
            # code...
        }
    }
}
```

**METHOD 2**

```
$obj = new CustomerPrivate();

if ($obj instanceof Customer)
{
   //CODE
}
else
{
    # code...
}
```

You can do this for any class you want

**EDITED**

Yes you can you interfaces, as you posted

```
interface Customer
{
}

class PrivateCustomer extends PrivatePerson implements Customer
{
     // Customers that are physical persons, but are CUSTOMERS!
}
```

**OR**

You can use traits.
Traits are very flexible but they are only supported in PHP 5.4 or higher

```
trait Customer
{

}

class PrivateCustomer extends PrivatePerson
{
    use Customer; //trait customer
    use OtherTrait;

  // Customers that are physical persons, but are CUSTOMERS!
}
```

**EDIT 2**

There are different algorithm for solving your problems which depends on your scenario. I cant imagine whole scenario but from your question. you want to have Customer type common in two different tree ( Person and Company ), in this context linear hierarchy is a problem, so i might have used something like this.

```
abstract class Contractor
{
    public function isCustomer()
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}


trait Customer
{
    public function isCustomer()
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

class CustomerCompany extends Company
{
    \\use Customer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if( !$this->isCustomer() )
        {
            throw new \Exception('ERROR', 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can objects of class CustomerPrivate be at the same time instances of Customer? How should I then define the class Customer?

Comment: Thank You very much! You helped me a lot.

Comment: I jus tried with traits, but it solves by problem partially. I can use the properties and methods in the traits for the objects, but the objects are not instances of the traits.... With interfaces I have the opposite situation ;-)

Comment: alternate solution is, which might be dirty, define a signature( property, const or method ) in trait and check for it,
eg if( method_exists($class, 'sgnature')
Do you have propblem with class **Customer extends Contractor** or vice versa

Comment: Actually I have exactly the following: eurosistemi\Contractor
extended by eurosistemi\PrivatePerson
extended by eurosistemi\ContractorPrivate

Comment: Actually I have exactly the following: Contractor extended by PrivatePerson extended by ContractorPrivate and Contractor extended by Company extended by CustomerCompany. How should I define Customer extends Contractor ;-) ? It is necessary that Company extends Contractor because I have many different  classes that extend directly Company and so on...

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it finally!

```
    Trait CustomerTrait {   

    }

    interface Customer {    

    }

    class CustomerCompany extends Company implements Customer { 

       use CustomerTrait;
    }   

   class CustomerPrivate extends ContractorPrivate implements Customer { 

       use CustomerTrait;
   }
```